# Create Master Detail Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, fastreport

i want create below(Image-1) report in Fast Report or Crystal Report.
i use of Grouping in Fast Report, But it work for one data source.

[Image-1](http://uupload.ir/files/fx7p_photo_2017-11-07_20-31-04.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this in Crystal Reports is to use subreports.  Each subreport can pull information from separate tables based on a parameter passed to the subreport.  The process for creating a subreport is well documented several places.  I hope this helps.  Glad to answer more specifically if you run into issues.